# How to summon Durnehviir?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

So I've got the shout in my shouts list and I've unlocked all three parts of it, but I can't seem to be able to use it all, just the first part.

Am I missing something? I still have a quest for 'Learn the first word of Durnehviir's shout' but it's showing as me having already got it.

What gives?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shout at the **ground** when using this shout. If done correctly he will be summoned immediately on the ground where the shout was directed. Be sure to press and hold to cast all three words to the shout or it will not work.

Additionally, from the [Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Summon_Durnehviir):

> The miscellaneous quest inventory indicating an open quest "Learn the first word of Durnehviir's Shout" is actually referring to Soul Tear, an entirely different Shout that Durnehviir will teach to the Dragonborn, one word at a time, during his first three summonings. Only after that will Durnehviir be of any real use in battle.

Comment: Also, he can be picky about having enough area to land, so shouting in a relatively flat, open area helps too.

Answer (score 8):

It took me 2 hours of searching online and walking around shouting at the ground.
Here is how to summon him.  Its simple and you will be slapping your forehead(I know I did).

The shout he gives you in the Soul Cairn is "Summon Durnheviir" (obviously).
This shout (unlike all the others) takes **three dragon souls** to unlock it completely.

**Very important: it is a three part shout!**

I am over emphasizing this because it seems to be the one thing the other forums I read do not explain.  I only had 1 unlocked so it wasn't greyed out in my list of shouts and appeared to be usable.  Not the case!

**Again: It will not work until you spend 3 dragon souls** to unlock all three words of the **Summon Durnheviir** shout.

Once that is done, go to a open area, relatively flat and shout at the ground in front of you.

You don't need to be in combat nor do you have to be on completely flat ground. Just a open space with no trees. (Mammoth camps or farms is a good place.) 
The area outside of Whiterun is where I did mine.

Shout at the ground in front of you and when he appears, he will give you one word of the soul tear shout.  He will then fly off and circle you for 5 minutes.  (You can use the wait function to speed this process up).

Shout again and he will give you another word.  Same process except you have to wait a couple hours.  Use the wait function again.  Shout a final time and you're good to go.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, pressing and holding the action button down for a long time makes absolutely no difference!

Answer (score 1):

Like *Lonestar50* said you are supposed to shout at the ground in front of you (just like you are doing when you are summoning an atronach) **BUT NOT TO CLOSE TO YOUSELF.** After all he is a dragon and need space to be summoned at.

Answer (score 0):

Summon Durnehviir

In order to call Durnehviir, you must press AND hold the shout,
while pointing to the ground in front of you.
A quick/short press does/will NOT work...

Answer (score 0):

when you do the main quest and you see alduin bringing back the dragon whrn your with delphine , use the shout on one of those circle platforms on the floor thats what i did

Answer (score -1):

Durnehviir isnt called like Odavhing, who flies to your location. He is actually summoned from the Soul Cairn. Therefore he needs plenty of space on the ground to be summoned at