# Will summoning Durnehviir level up Conjuration like I used a Conjuration spell?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

The [TES wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Conjuration_%28Skyrim%29#Trivia) says this about the 'Summon Durnehviir' shout:

> The shout Summon Durnehviir functions as a conjuration spell unlike Call of Valor. Therefore, if there is already a creature summoned, the shout will replace the summoned creature, also, summoning something else while Durnheviir is still active will prematurely end him.

Also, [summoning Durnehviir requires you to shout at (target) the ground](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/79781/4797) unlike the other summoning dragon shouts, and like the Conjuration summoning spells.

Based on this, I'm wondering if summoning Durnehviir will also level up Conjuration like I used a Conjuration spell (assuming there are enemies around and I am in combat). Can anyone confirm or deny?

Comment: Don't see why it was downvoted either. Personally think it is a good question. Hope you get an answer.

Comment: @One-One Not really that trivial since [summoning Durnehviir](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Summon_Durnehviir) has a cooldown and it won't be easy to spam that shout. I asked here in case someone already knows about this or has experienced leveling up Conjuration from summoning Durnehviir.

Comment: Step 1: Make mod that removes the cooldown for the Durnehviir shout. Step 2: Spam Durnehviir shout. That said, I wouldn't think it would level conjuration; conjuration is a category of *spells*, and shouts aren't spells.

Comment: As far as I know no other shout levels a skill (even those which closely mimic a skill ability), so I find it unlikely that this one does.

Comment: @ObliviousSage "*...conjuration is a category of spells, and shouts aren't spells*" What made me ask the question is that 'Summon Durnehviir' is a quite unique shout, in that it functions like a Conjuration spell. Also, we all know how much Bethesda games are bugged (or has additional unnoted features). =) e.g. Remember the [Necromage-Vampire bug/feature](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Necromage_%28perk%29#Notes)?

Comment: I cannot level-up my conjuration even with conjuration spells, so I cannot confirm either way.

Comment: @One-One that's not how you're supposed to vote >.< http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7241/26487

Comment: @shanodin That's how it should work. However, in practice, some of this site's users don't really follow that guideline, especially people who love downvoting. Some downvote due to hating a certain category of questions, like all lore questions, and some downvote due to comments of a user unrelated to the question at hand. E.g. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128463/who-or-what-is-mystara If other downvoters do that (and it is indeed not against site policy to do so), then One-One is free to (up/down)vote this question for any reason he deems valid too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**. Summoning Durnehviir is not a conjuration spell - it simply functions in the same way as one, therefore obeying the same rules. Only casting conjuration spells on valid targets increases the skill.

**How I can be so sure** - I've got a variety (if I tell you exactly how many, that means admitting how much time I've spent in Tamriel) of high level characters. I've never summoned anyone with most of them, and the only places they have ever earned conjuration skill points has been books. I had a quick check before posting, and summoning Durnehviir didn't change the progress at all on the little bar which tracks progress in a skill.