# Who or what is Mystara?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion, the-elder-scrolls-series

In TES IV: Oblivion, [beggars](http://uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Beggars) will occasionally say "*Blessings of* [one of the [Nine Divines](http://uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Nine_Divines#Nine_Divines)] *upon ye*" after you have conversed with them. They will also occasionally say "*Blessings of Mystara upon ye*". Mystara, however, is not one of the Nine Divines.

[I've searched the UESP wiki](http://uesp.net/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=Mystara&button=) and found nothing related to Mystara as mentioned in Oblivion.

**Who or what is Mystara?**

[image: a beggar saying "Blessings of Mystara upon ye"]

I came upon this [UESP forums thread](http://forums.uesp.net/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=19728) where users mentioned that it could be an easter egg, and/or a reference to "*a campaign setting for the Dungeons & Dragons role playing game*". Can anyone confirm/deny, or expound on how these relate to how Mystara is mentioned in this context?

Comment: Same thing with Anu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Mystara" is an in-joke and refers to the [D&D setting of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystara). It comes to Oblivion via its lead game designer [Ken Rolston](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Rolston) who was involved in the creation of the Mystara D&D setting and authored two of the background books for it:

- [The Emirates of Ylaruam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emirates_of_Ylaruam)
- [The Northern Reaches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Northern_Reaches) (with [Elizabeth Danforth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liz_Danforth))